# How to get share point sites data using office 365 api?

Tags: c#, sharepoint, office365, azure-connect

I am exploring Office 365 Api for accessing Files from the following links

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/howto/common-file-tasks-client-library

I successfully get all the documents from my one drive but i want to know that how can i get data from sites or share point sites. I search on Google a lot but unable to find any thing.

Here is the link of full rest api of office 365 files section rest operations

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/files-rest-operations

Please guide me Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring to accessing contents in default doc library of another SharePoint site, you could provide the site path as below. It will point to the contents in the default doc library. The user should have sufficient level of access to the site.

SharePoint sites: https://{tenant}.sharepoint.com/{site-path}/_api/v1.0